# iPhone:Tabbar item actions are not happening

Tags: iphone

I created a window application, which has a tabbar controller with four tabbar items. Each tabbar items are linked with a tableview. I have also set Navigation bar for each tabbar items. 
I have appdelegate file, which calls the first tableview controller of which is set for first tabbar item. 
I am trying to retrieve and do an action whenever a tabbar item is clicked. For that, i tried to add 
"- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item" and 
"- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UITableViewController *)viewController"

in my first tableview controller, but it is not at all responding whenever i click any tabbar items. 
My question is, if i create a window based application and added tabbar controller, tableview and navigation bar in .XIB file, is it not possible to access and do an action programatically  whenever a tabbar item is clicked? (or) Am i doing anything wrong?

Please help me to resolve this and share your ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone provide your suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to resolve this issue using "- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UITableViewController *)viewController" by setting [myTabbarController setDelegate:self]; in the current file. Thanks